# Scheduled Email in Outlook (Salesforce)

Tags: email, salesforce-for-outlook, outlook

When I go to send an email it is not sending at the exact time that I need it to send. It is sending slightly before (2-3 minutes earlier).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert, so this is a **comment** rather than an **answer**. But from my experiences, I can say that there are 2 ways for that. - The first and logical explanation is that, SFMC has a lot of different operations going on in the background. (Automations, so it takes some time to reflect) - Second thing is that, your DE is massive (but this option is not possible since you're testing it, right?) I hope that's helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention,
I found something about it 

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_schedule_send_later_things_to_know.htm&type=5

Comment: No worries, anytime :) That looks good yeah! Sometimes it's just there you know, to check out original source :D